# send email notification using gcp cloud function

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

i have used below code to send email using GCP cloud function, code compiled successfully but while click on "RUN TEST" not geting any email notification.

Note: i have not specfied any gmail credentials in function.

could you please guide me how to proceed further

```
def email(request):
import os
from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import Mail, Email
from python_http_client.exceptions import HTTPError

sg = SendGridAPIClient(os.environ['EMAIL_API_KEY'])

html_content = "<p>Hello World!</p>"

message = Mail(
    to_emails="xyz.k@gmail.com",
    from_email=Email('abc@gmail.com', ""),
    subject="Hello world",
    html_content=html_content
    )

try:
    response = sg.send(message)
    return f"email.status_code={response.status_code}"

except HTTPError as e:
    return e.message
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation.

Comment: there is no issue with indentation ,code compiled successfully.